# Unable to produce tensorboard in Keras pre trained model

Tags: python, keras, tensorboard

I am building Pre trained inception model for image classification in keras
i am trying to produce tensorboard but getting errors like "Unable to create directory:
code :

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from time import time
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()))
history= model_inc.fit(trainX,trainY,epochs=9,batch_size=16,
                       validation_data=(testX,testY),
                       shuffle=True,verbose=1,
                       callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a static directory instead of the timestamped one?

Comment: Yes Have tried that too @ixeption

Comment: Hmma nd are you sure that you have privileges to create a directory at this place?

Comment: Yes @ixeption I do have

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem due to Python on Windows. Try replacing the path of `logdir` in `tensorboard` to **`tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join("logs",time())`**.

You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57093370/11530462) for more details on the same.