# Trying to save a tensorflow model but failing to create directory "failed to create a directory: /tmp/serving_savemodel\1565577669"

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to save a DNN classifier model so I can generate a tflite model, but in the last line, when trying to export to directory, I get error below:

> failed to create a directory: /tmp/serving_savemodel\1565577669

```
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feat_cols)

export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)

servable_model_dir = "/tmp/serving_savemodel"

servable_model_path = dnn_model.export_savedmodel(servable_model_dir, export_input_fn)
```

Comment: Seems like a permission error. Could you paste the whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in my windows machine.
I solved it by using as path separator "\" instead of "/".

Example for your case:

```
    servable_model_dir = r"\tmp\serving_savemodel"
```

Related question: [Tensorflow error failed to create directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093053/tensorflow-error-failed-to-create-directory)